# Bash and dialog UI, how to change color dynamically

Tags: linux, bash, shell, colors, dialog

I have a simple bash script, which I use to maintain some log etc files on a server, and most of the time the tools works in "normal mode". For UI I use the `dialog` tool.

However, sometimes I have some condition that requires more careful attention, and I would like at those times to change the background color of dialog, to draw more attention to the issue.

I know that by changing the `screen_color` attribute in `.dialogrc`, I can define custom colors for the dialogs, but that affects all windows, and is not what I want.

Is there some way to **dynamically** set this variable so that only specific dialogs would have different colors, and everything else unaffected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a given `dialog` process, you can select a specific configuration file using the environment variable `DIALOGRC` (see [manual](http://invisible-island.net/dialog/manpage/dialog.html#h2-ENVIRONMENT)).